# Rewrite URL -> Subfolder rename --> htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am in need for some HTACCESS support here. I dont believe it is very complex if I read through all the comments on similar request but simply dont get it working on my side - even after rebuilding the Permalinks.

This is my situation: I use WordPress 4.2.2 and have a theme with a portfolio. The slug of this portfolio is /portfolio/ which I want to change to /examples/

Now I have a second slug for the categories of this portfolio /PORT_CAT/ which also need to be rewritten to /example-cat/

The url is like:  http://wwww.domain.com/portfolio and http://www.domain.com/port_cat/

Can somebody support me with the URL rewrite state to add to my HTACCESS and if required additional steps to rebuild the structure properly so it reflects in the front-end/browser?

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: Why don't you just change the slug in Wordpress?

Comment: as per my understanding not possible with Porto Wordpress theme. http://newsmartwave.net/wordpress/porto/demo11/portfolio/    With this theme there is no actual Page created for the Portfolio, it is a custom post type

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but I'm not sure why you can't change the URI in Wordpress.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^examples/?$ /portfolio/ [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^example-cat/?$ /port_cat/ [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks! but just tested it and it doesnt work. My htaccess looks like:                        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On
>RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/?$ /examples/ [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^port_cat/?$ /example-cat/ [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule></code>

Comment: I can't see any issues with you htaccess config, although it's hard to read all bunched up like that. You should remove `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` as I can't see that it would do anything useful. What's your domain?

Comment: Thanks PiranhaGeorge: domain is iotmashups dot come

Comment: Is the .htaccess currently configured as above?

Comment: Okay. I've fixed my rules, I had your requirements backwards.